# Disappearing Cursor

Tags: cursor

This is a problem I have when using GUI Emacs. I don't have this problem with terminal Emacs.

After starting it, I don't see any cursor.

I've put this at the bottom of my .emacs file

```
(setq-default cursor-type '(box . 4))
(set-cursor-color "#FF0000")
```

, but I still have to evaluate that after I start emacs, to be able to see any cursor.

I'd also like it to be a 'block', but I only found 'box' to be working.

Any pointers?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set-cursor-color` applies to the current frame — check its documentation. (What Emacs calls a frame is what most of the rest of the world calls a window.) Depending on the window system, the initial frame object may or may not already have been created when `.emacs` runs, so your `set-cursor-color` call will either apply only to the initial frame, or have no visible effect.

To make it apply to all frames, set the `cursor-color` parameters in the [default frame parameters list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Initial-Parameters.html#index-default_002dframe_002dalist).

```
(setq default-frame-alist `((cursor-color . "#FF0000")
                            ,@default-frame-alist))
```

As for the cursor type, the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cursor-Parameters.html#index-cursor_002dtype_002c-a-frame-parameter) mentions `(box . size)` as an option, but [this was added in Emacs 28.1](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.28#L678). In Emacs 27.2 on Linux with Xaw or GTK, setting `cursor-type` to an unsupported value doesn't result in any error and seems to be equivalent to `hollow`. So I guess you'll have to settle for plain `box` or for `(bar . 4)` until you upgrade.

Comment: Yup, thanks;) that solved it;). For the other part, a block is a solid block, vs what I see now is a hollow box, so it's not filled. It's like an inactive cursor, but it's actually active. Having it like this makes both inactive and active cursor have the same look, so hard to distinguish.

Comment: @JasonHunter I see, so you want `box` but you're getting `hollow`. Well, I guess that's because your Emacs is too old and doesn't support `(box . WIDTH)` — I've updated my answer.

Comment: Great; thanks;) I upgraded and now it's all aok;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see what you did there. :-)

Try:

```
(setq make-pointer-invisible nil)
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about the pointer.

Comment: You're right. Ho hum.